# Sorted structure with fast insertion and head/floor removal many elements

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

What is the fastest sorted structure for insertions and removal many elements higher/lesser or equal to given value? I will describe it in few steps:

1. Starting point = [1,2,3]
2. New value 5 = [1,2,3,5]
3. Next new value 4 = [1,2,3,4,5]
4. Next new value 4 again = [1,2,3,4,4,5] (4's are treated the same)
5. removeTail(4) = [1,2,3] (it returns removed elements: [4,4,5]
6. removeHead(2) = [3] (it returns removed elements: [1,2]

The structure will be accessed from single thread, memory consumption doesn't matter. I would like to achive the fastest (at least O(logN)) complexity. I wonder if I should use some B-Trees but it seems like too much re-balancing overhead so maybe instead I should try skip-list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are OK with *likely* `O(logn)` performance for each of these operations, a simple probabilistic [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) sounds perfect here.

Insertion and deletions are native to Skip List.

`RemoveTail()` and `RemoveHead()` are simply finding the element, and trimming everything "above it" (and by above it, I mean the actual path you used to find the element) to the left or to the right. Each such operation is `O(logn)` on average, as  you touch only the nodes in the path (and maybe one adjacent for each of them).

If you want deterministic - this could be done as well, but will be more complicated to remove elements and rebalance while keeping deterministic structure, though not impossible.